# Name of the condition $AB=BA$, $AB^*=B^*A$

Tags: matrices

For two square complex matrices $A, B$ of the same order, what is the name of the condition

$AB=BA$, $AB^*=B^*A$?

Is this condition popular? Here $A^*$ means the transpose conjugate of $A$.

Comment: I would say $A$ belongs to the [commutant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutant) of $\{B,B^{\ast}\}$. I don't know if there is a more specialized terminology.

Comment: I would like to know if someone used this condition in his/her work.

Comment: Well, it's used a lot in the theory of operator algebra, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_bicommutant_theorem which is a cornerstone of the theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume that $B$ is a normal matrix i.e $B^{*}B=BB^{*}$ and $A$ and $B$ commute, then you will automatically get that $B^{*}A=AB^{*}$.
It is called Fuglede-Putnam Theorem and it is even true for normal operators from $\mathcal{B}(H)$ - all bounded linear operators on $H$, where $H$ is a Hilbert spaces.
In your case $H=\mathbb{C}^{n}$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede's_theorem

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about this theorem it can be found in "Putnam's generalization" section.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal operators from $\mathcal{B}(H,K)$"?

Comment: I had a mistake cos the theorem in full generality involves possibly different two normal operators $N$ and $M$ and one can be on $H$ and second on $K$ since $A$ is the bounded operator from $K$ to $H$ such that $NA=AM$.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ and $B$ "doubly commute," some say.  You will find at least some evidence of this by searching for `"doubly commuting matrices"`. Leaving out "matrices" will find many doubly commuting operators on Hilbert space, meaning operators that commute with each other and with each other's adjoints.